# PHP Unit Test: How to test a class that implements an interface from another package?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to test a class that implements an interface that is defined outside the scope of the classes package (i.e. I pull it in as a dependency using composer during integration).

I would like to test this concrete class without having to pull in the interface it depends on. Is there anyway to test this in php unit test?

At the moment I can't even instantiate an instance as the interface is obviously not found.

Comment: Why don't you simply include that dependency in your tests? I mean, your class depends on it, so there's nothing wrong including it in the test.

Comment: Thats not the method of testing I am following. All dependencies should be mocked, and the package unit tested without relying on these dependencies.

Comment: So, you want to test your class that relies on an external dependency, without including that dependency. Well, I hope you see the irony in that statement. ;-)

Comment: Not on interfaces imho. An interface is a contract you want your classes to adhere to. What is the point of using an external one if you obv. don't want your classes to adhere to it during the tests. That's my opinion, so there's absolutely no reason for BM here. Look, maybe [this](http://donniewa.com/2014/04/phpunit-testing-interface-injection-mocks/) can help you. You could also circumvent everything by creating an abstract class that implements that interface and have your classes extend that one (which can be mocked easily).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface that your class is not a dependency in that sense...  There is nothing to mock.  You just need to make sure that the class is an instance of the interface in your tests for that class.

You need to change something about your testing environment so that the interface is available in order to test your class.  So that you can instantiate and test the behavior of the methods that the interface specifies.

Dependency injection is about objects that your code NEEDS not what your code is.  An interface or an abstract class are not dependencies.  Even though your code "depends" on those things existing.

Dependencies are external objects that you class needs to do something.  Interfaces and abstract classes define what are you class is.

Comment: that makes more sense than the 'helpful' comment of  nietonfir. The issue I have is that the external package supplies an interface which I must implement. I was hoping to test in isolation and not have to pull in all the dependencies

Comment: If it is really a pain to import the external package, you can create the interface in your test file before declaring the test class.  Though this can result in problems with trying to redeclare the same interface multiple times if you are not careful.

Comment: But doesn't that remove some of the usefulness of the test? What if the (real) interface changes?

Comment: @nietonfir It does and I am not really advocating just creating the interface.  Since I don't know what the issues are with importing the package are, I was offering that as a possible solution if the issues were exceptionally painful and difficult.  But importing the package is the best solution.

Comment: Probably right, importing the package will probably be the solution. I just had this view in my mind that i could somehow testing everything in isolation i.e unit test. Importing the package means I'm effectively doing integration tests

Comment: No an integration test would test how your objects interact with each other.  This is still a unit test as you are testing the one class.  That aside don't get hung up "unit tests" vs "integration tests"